# Add UserControl dynamically or programmatically inside Grid

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn, ninject
I want to create a plane Cockpit with a background image (inside grid)

and add dynamically (following the type of plane) lot of usercontrol (like lamps, switches or gauges at different position)

I know to add dynamically Usercontrol behind code (Grid.Add.Children)

but is it possible with Caliburn , using convention names and stay in MVVM? or I have to used code behind.. I have no idea to take the problem.

File: BootStrapper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using Caliburn.Micro;

using Ninject;
using WpfApp2.ButtonAndSwitches;

namespace WpfApp2.Bootstrap
{
    public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        private IKernel kernel;

        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            kernel = ServiceBootstrapper.Create();
            kernel.Bind<IWindowManager>().To<WindowManager>().InSingletonScope();
            kernel.Bind<MainWindowViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayRootViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>();
        }
        private void OnSettingsLoaded()
        {

        }
        protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return kernel.Get(service);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(service);
        }

        private void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            kernel.Get<ILog>().Error(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
        }
    }

    public static class ServiceBootstrapper
    {
        public static IKernel Create()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            BindCommon(kernel);

            return kernel;
        }

        private static void BindCommon(StandardKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<EventAggregator>().InSingletonScope();
        }
    }
}
```

InstrumentsViewModel.cs

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using WpfApp2.ButtonAndSwitches;
using WpfApp2.CommonEvents;
using WpfApp2.Extensions;
using IEventAggregator = WpfApp2.Events.IEventAggregator;
namespace WpfApp2
{
    public class InstrumentsViewModel : Screen
    {
        private bool show;
        private InstrumentsView instrumentsview;
        private MainWindowViewModel mainwindow;
        private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;
        private readonly int panel;
        private readonly IWindowManager windowmanager;

        private string _backgroundFile;
        public InstrumentsViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IWindowManager windowmanager, int panel)
        {
            this.panel = panel;
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            this.windowmanager = windowmanager;
        }

        protected override void OnViewReady(object view)
        {
            if (panel == 0)
            {
                instrumentsview = view as InstrumentsView;

                RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;

                var backgroundFilestring = @"F:\Ikarus-master\Ikarus\Images\Backgounds\A10CBackGround.png";

                BackImage = (backgroundFilestring);


                UserControl userControl = (UserControl)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("WpfApp2.ButtonAndSwitches.SwitchOn_Off_OnView"));
                instrumentsview.MainGrid.Children.Add(userControl);
            }
        }

        public string BackImage
        {
            get => _backgroundFile;
            set
            {
                _backgroundFile = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BackImage);
            }
        }
        public void ButtonClose()
        {
            instrumentsview.Close();
        }
        public void BackImage_GotFocus()
        {
        }

        public void Window_MouseMove()
        {
        }
        public void Window_MouseDown()
        {
        }
        public void Window_GotFocus()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Sample of Switch

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Caliburn.Micro;
using WpfApp2.CommonEvents;

namespace WpfApp2.ButtonAndSwitches
{
    public class SwitchOn_Off_OnViewModel:Screen
    {
        private string pictureUp = "";
        private string pictureMiddle = "";
        private string pictureDown = "";

        private int state = 1;


        public SwitchOn_Off_OnViewModel()
        {
            SwitchMiddle = @"F:\Ikarus-master\Ikarus\Images\Switches\switch_mid2.png";
        }

        private string _Switchmiddle;

        public string SwitchMiddle
        {
            get
            {
                return _Switchmiddle;
            }
            set
            {
                _Switchmiddle = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SwitchMiddle);
            }
        }

        public void Light_MouseWheel()
        {

        }

        public void UpperRec_MouseDown()
        {
                if (++state > 2) state = 2;
                SetValue(state, true);
        }

        public void UpperRec_MouseUp()
        {
            SetValue(1, true);
        }

        public void LowerRec_MouseDown()
        {
                if (--state < 0) state = 0;
                SetValue(state, true);
        }

        public void LowerRec_MouseUp()
        {
            SetValue(1, true);
        }
        private void SetValue(int _state, bool _event, bool dontReset = false)
        {
                if (_state == 2)
                {

                }

                if (_state == 1)
                {

                }

                if (_state == 0)
                {

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Now all view associated

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="MainWindowView" Height="158.241" Width="206.594" >
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="ShowOrCloseCockpit" Content="{Binding showorclose}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Height="50"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

    <Window x:Class="WpfApp2.InstrumentsView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.ButtonAndSwitches"
        Title="Instruments"
        Width="1920"
        Height="1080"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        cal:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action Window_GotFocus()];[Event Mousedown] = [Action Window_MouseDown()];[Event MouseMove] = [Action Window_MouseMove()]"
        Topmost="True"
        WindowStyle="None">
    <Border Background="Transparent"
            BorderBrush="#00FFA500"
            BorderThickness="0"
            CornerRadius="0">
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid"
              Background="#00060606"
              Opacity="1.0">
            <Image x:Name="BackImage" cal:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action BackImage_GotFocus()]"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   Stretch="Fill" />
            <Button x:Name="btCloseRight"
                    cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ButtonClose()]"
                    Width="25"
                    Height="24"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Content="X"
                    Foreground="#FF190301"
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.895,7.292">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFF3F3F3" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#FFEBEBEB" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#FFDDDDDD" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFAFAC68" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock x:Name="MousePosition" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFBF8F8"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

and the Switch View

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp2.ButtonAndSwitches.SwitchOn_Off_OnView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="70" cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseWheel]=[Light_MouseWheel]">
    <Grid Name="Switch"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image x:Name="SwitchUp"
               Width="70"
               Height="150"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Image x:Name="SwitchMiddle" 
               Width="70"
               Height="150"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <Image x:Name="SwitchDown"
               Width="70"
               Height="150"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="UpperRec" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Mousedown]=[UpperRec_MouseDown];[Event MouseUP]=[UpperRec_MouseUp]"
                   Width="60"
                   Height="50"
                   Margin="5,20,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Fill="#00EEDB21"
                   Stroke="#00000000" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="LowerRec" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Mousedown]=[LowerRec_MouseDown];[Event MouseUP]=[LowerRec_MouseUp]"
                   Width="60"
                   Height="50"
                   Margin="5,80,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Fill="#00EEDB21"
                   Stroke="#00000000"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="DesignFrame"
                   Width="70"
                   Height="150"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Fill="#00EEDB21"
                   Stroke="#FFF38501"
                   StrokeThickness="4" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

when I click on button from Mainview, i launch via windowsManager the instrumentsView

the problem is to add dynamically the switch (more then) onside the view instruments... how I could load the usercontrol and bind with the view (Caliburn??)

[Sample of background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgalB.jpg)

[Sample of Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c10G0.png)

Comment: Show us your (code) effort..

Comment: Hi Jereon i have added the code..